# Why am I getting Error 3010014: Invalid symbol when I perform a simple transfer

Tags: cleos, transactions, tokens, transfer

**INFO**

- Jungle Testnet 2.0
- `<myaccount1>` has funds

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

Just perform a simple transfer of EOS such as:

1. `cleos transfer <myaccount1> <myaccount2> "1.0000 EOS"`
2. `cleos transfer <myaccount1> <myaccount2> "1.0000 EOS" -p <myaccount1>@active`

**ERROR**

> Error 3010014: Invalid symbol Error Details: invalid symbol: -EOS

Answer (score 2):

Nodeos: v1.5

CDT: v1.5

```
cleos -u https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443 transfer chesseosches eosiostackmm "1.0000 EOS"

executed transaction: 861f71e89de2ae7d12bf2738e09bd2501e672e17bb9f4727f1d715cccedcd38a  128 bytes  790 us
#   eosio.token <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"chesseosches","to":"eosiostackmm","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":""}
#  chesseosches <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"chesseosches","to":"eosiostackmm","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":""}
#  eosiostackmm <= eosio.token::transfer        {"from":"chesseosches","to":"eosiostackmm","quantity":"1.0000 EOS","memo":""}
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet         ]
```

If I had to guess, you just weren't adding the API extension.  And if you had a local node running, SYS is the native token by default instead of "EOS".